# Change Title of Sharepoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a CallbackConfirm.aspx and attached the sharepoint master page in SP 2007.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" masterpagefile="~masterurl/custom.master" title="CallbackConfirm" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>
```

[image]

But then it gives me full site URL. I simple want to see the page title.

Where do i need to make the changes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the ContentPlaceholder with id PlaceHolderPageTitle

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
  Callback Confirmation
</asp:Content>
```